# Why do intercommunicating states have the same recurrence status?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I am studying my reading material for the markov chains section of my degree.
In particular, the section I'm confused about is on the topic of recurrence and transience.
There is a theorem, which states,

> Intercommunicating states have the same recurrence status.
>   Suppose $i \leftrightarrow j$ and state $i$ is recurrent, then state $j$ is also recurrent.

That's fine and intuitive and I understand that. However, there is a note beneath that which confuses me. It says,

> This theorem implies that, if $C$ is an irreducible subset of states, then either the states in $C$ are all recurrent or all transient.

Now I try to reconcile this with the definition of an irreducible set of states. That is,

> A set $C$ of states is called irreducible if $i \leftrightarrow j$ $
> \forall i, j \in C$.

That means I can pick any state in $C$ and find a way to get back to that state. In other words, there are no transient states. Which to my mind, confirms that "if $C$ is an irreducible subset of states, then the states in $C$ are all recurrent". Therefore, I do not understand how an irreducible set of states can possibly consist of *only* transient states. Can somebody explain this please? Maybe there is a misunderstanding in my chain of reasoning?

---

Edit: I think I have figured out why this is by drawing this diagram:

States 1 and 2 are transient, since given enough steps, we will transition to absorbing state 3. But 1 and 2 belong to the irreducible set $C$.

[image: Intercommunication with transcience]

Comment: I think you may be confused about the definition of a transient state.  A state is transient if the probability of returning to it is less than $1.$  You seem to be assuming it must be $0$.  There's a good discussion [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch13.pdf)

Comment: @saulspatz yes you're right